# link: invalid option -- 's'

Tags: centos, make

I tried to execute a makefile in CentOS 7.5 but the following error is stopping me:

```
make export
make[1]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config'
make[3]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config/mkdepend'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `export'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config/mkdepend'
/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config/nsinstall -R nsinstall ../dist/bin
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config'
make[2]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/editline'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `export'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/editline'
make[2]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/shell'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `export'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/shell'
make[2]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/jsapi-tests'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `export'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/jsapi-tests'
make[2]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/tests'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `export'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/tests'
/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/config/nsinstall -R -m 644 js-config.h jsautocfg.h /shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src/jsautokw.h js.msg jsanalyze.h jsapi.h jsarray.h jsarena.h jsatom.h jsbit.h jsbool.h jsclist.h jsclone.h jscntxt.h jscompat.h jsdate.h jsdbgapi.h jsdhash.h jsdtoa.h jsemit.h jsfun.h jsfriendapi.h jsgc.h jscell.h jsgcchunk.h jsgcstats.h jscompartment.h jshash.h jsinterp.h jsinttypes.h jsiter.h jslock.h jslong.h jsmath.h jsobj.h jsobjinlines.h json.h jsopcode.tbl jsopcode.h jsopcodeinlines.h jsotypes.h jsparse.h jsproxy.h jsprf.h jsprobes.h jspropertycache.h jspropertycacheinlines.h jspropertytree.h jsproto.tbl jsprvtd.h jspubtd.h jsreflect.h jsregexp.h jsscan.h jsscope.h jsscript.h jsscriptinlines.h jsstaticcheck.h jsstdint.h jsstr.h jstracer.h jshotloop.h jstypedarray.h jstypes.h jsutil.h jsvector.h jstl.h jshashtable.h jsversion.h jswrapper.h jsxdrapi.h jsxml.h jsval.h jsvalue.h prmjtime.h jsbuiltins.h ./nanojit/Assembler.h ./nanojit/Allocator.h ./nanojit/CodeAlloc.h ./nanojit/Containers.h ./nanojit/LIR.h ./nanojit/LIRopcode.tbl ./nanojit/avmplus.h ./nanojit/Fragmento.h ./nanojit/Native.h ./nanojit/NativeCommon.h ./nanojit/NativeX64.h ./nanojit/njconfig.h ./nanojit/njcpudetect.h ./nanojit/RegAlloc.h ./nanojit/nanojit.h ./nanojit/VMPI.h ./tracejit/Writer.h ./perf/jsperf.h ./dist/include
mkdir -p nanojit
make[1]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src'
make libs
make[1]: Entering directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src'
rm -f libmozjs185.so
link -shared -h libmozjs185.so -o libmozjs185.so  jsanalyze.o jsapi.o jsarena.o jsarray.o jsatom.o jsbool.o jsclone.o jscntxt.o jscompartment.o jsdate.o jsdbgapi.o jsdhash.o jsdtoa.o jsemit.o jsexn.o jsfriendapi.o jsfun.o jsgc.o jsgcchunk.o jsgcstats.o jshash.o jsinterp.o jsinvoke.o jsiter.o jslock.o jslog2.o jsmath.o jsnativestack.o jsnum.o jsobj.o json.o jsopcode.o jsparse.o jsproxy.o jsprf.o jsprobes.o jspropertycache.o jspropertytree.o jsreflect.o jsregexp.o jsscan.o jsscope.o jsscript.o jsstr.o jstypedarray.o jsutil.o jswrapper.o jsxdrapi.o jsxml.o prmjtime.o sharkctl.o jstracer.o Assembler.o Allocator.o CodeAlloc.o Containers.o Fragmento.o LIR.o njconfig.o RegAlloc.o avmplus.o NativeX64.o jsbuiltins.o VMPI.o Writer.o MethodJIT.o StubCalls.o Compiler.o FrameState.o FastArithmetic.o FastOps.o StubCompiler.o MonoIC.o PolyIC.o ImmutableSync.o InvokeHelpers.o Retcon.o TrampolineCompiler.o checks.o conversions.o diy-fp.o v8-dtoa.o fast-dtoa.o platform.o utils.o Assertions.o ExecutableAllocatorPosix.o ExecutableAllocatorWin.o ExecutableAllocatorOS2.o ExecutableAllocator.o ARMAssembler.o Logging.o MacroAssemblerARM.o MacroAssemblerX86Common.o RegexCompiler.o RegexJIT.o pcre_compile.o pcre_exec.o pcre_tables.o pcre_xclass.o pcre_ucp_searchfuncs.o jsperf.o pm_linux.o     -lpthread   -Wl,-rpath-link,/bin -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -lplds4 -lplc4 -lnspr4 -Wl,-soname,libmozjs185.so.1.0 -ldl  -lm -ldl  
link: invalid option -- 's'
Try 'link --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [libmozjs185.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/shilpa/audiocodes/unimrcp-1.5.0/GrammarSrv/libs/smonkey/common/js/src'
make: *** [default] Error 2
[root@localhost src]#
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the whole command that make runs? It usually outputs it, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you intended to call the linker `ld` but rather called the program `link` that exist to permit the super user to create a hardlink to a directory.

If the makefile does not contain any direct call to `link`, you should check your environment on how e.g. the make macro `LD` could get the value `link`.

I recommend to call:

```
make -n -p
```

catch the output in a file and then look for `link` inside that output.

If you see that with:

```
make -f /dev/null -p
```

as well, the values is most likely imported from the environment.

Comment: Is there some current system where creating hard links to directories works?

Comment: Due to the historic design flaw in UNIX, linking directories was needed in the 1970s and AT&T insisted to have this in the POSIX 1992 standard. Systems derived from or compatible to SVr4 allow it for the V7 filesystem and for UFS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @schily if you see in shared make file command 'link'  is not used  but 'ln' is used. I have replaced ln with ld and tried but same error is reappeared and tried to execute using sudo make(to execute as super user) but of no use.

Comment: @amb, it's not about file linking, it's about symbol linking in the making of an executable. You must have something like `LD=link` in your environment or in some file used in the building process, and/or the `configure` script if any was not run properly or is buggy.

Comment: You are right and I added a hint on how to track that problem to the answer.

Comment: Hey thank you. I changed LD=link to LD=ld in configure file mentioned error is cleared but new problem is raised as ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,-rpath-link,/bin'. Am sorry since am new to linux and make file am not able to catch the problems so easily.

Comment: Runpath is a problem with some variant of linkers that are used on Linux. Please have a look at the man page of your distro. The official option name on `ELF` systems is `-R`, but the GNU variants of the linker are not based on standard ELF tools.

Comment: Thank you every one for guiding. I cann't believe that this error disappeared by re-executing make file after "make distclean " :)

Answer (score -3):

Seems like you are trying to run a shell with few shell commands so you have multiple lines of shell scripts code in your shell script file.

There are several line breaks are there and refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Each shell script line should ends with `LR` characters but actually your shell script file is ends with `CRLF` character.

To change `CRLF` to `LF`

**1. Notepad++**

1. To check line vreak character => View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line
2. To Replace `CRLF` with `LF`
   [image]

try to run your shell script file and it should work now.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please edit your post to elaborate why you think that the end-of-line coding is the issue here, nothing in the output shown by the OP seems to indicate that.

Comment: I have had same strange issue and I added solutions from my perspective. I don't know what you are expecting here